# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void' in Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In trying to execute this action, and while I'm getting the correct data in response on the backend, the `data` variable is coming back undefined. I'm also getting a TS error saying `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'`

action/churches.js

```
export const getChurchesBySearch = (searchQuery) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await apis.getChurchesBySearch(searchQuery);
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_BY_SEARCH", payload: data });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Like I mentioned, the correct response is being returned on the backend, but when assigning it to `data`, `data` is undefined.

Here are the other files:
apis/churches.js

```
export const getChurchesBySearch = (searchQuery) => {
  console.log(searchQuery.city);
  axios.get(
    `${url}/search?city=${searchQuery.city}&denom=${searchQuery.denom}`
  );
};
```

controller/churches.js

```
export const getChurchesBySearch = async (req, res) => {
  const { city, denom } = req.query;
  try {
    const churches = await Church.find({
      $or: [{ city: city }, { denom: denom }],
    }).sort({ attend: -1 });
    res.status(200).json(churches);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement in the `getChurchesBySearch` function.

```
export const getChurchesBySearch = (searchQuery) => {
  console.log(searchQuery.city);
  return axios.get(
    `${url}/search?city=${searchQuery.city}&denom=${searchQuery.denom}`
  );
};
```